# CruiseControl.net build fails even through MSBuild task succeeds

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I've installed CruiseControl.net for the first time and I'm having trouble getting my solution to build. It is strange because it builds in VS2008 just fine. I've got a very simple config file with this MSBuild task:

```
      <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <projectFile>MySolutionFile.sln</projectFile>
        <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag</buildArgs>
      </msbuild>
```

There are no errors or warnings displayed when I look at the build report, but it does say in red that "This project doesn't have any tests". I don't know whether this is causing the build to fail.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally have to read through the nant scripts and CC.Net config file to figure out what checks are being performed and troubleshoot these problems.  I would bet that there is something that is looking for successful tests.  If you are using Cruise Control for the fist time, you might want to check out CI Factory first.  It uses Cruise Control as part of it's "suite" of build management tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try building it via the command line msbuild first eg.

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe MySolutionFile.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Once youve got it wotrking like that then host it in CCnet.